# Quando vamos ter um podcast no SOpt?

Tags: novo-recurso

Estava vendo alguns tópicos da sessão "blog" no canto direito do SOpt e me deparei com o alguns tópicos do SOen (isso é um bug?). Me senti um pouco mal por ver que o SOen tinha um podcast e eu não sabia, rsrs. Achei muito interessante alguns que eles já gravaram. Gosto bastante de podcasts pois passo um bom tempo programando e gosto de ouvir enquanto trabalho, parece que aproveito mais o meu tempo, rsrs.

Enfim, o podcast é logicamente em inglês. Teremos algum em português também?

Comment: Não posso falar pela empresa, mas provavelmente nunca já que eles acabaram com os blogs das comunidades por falta de atividade (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291741/140010). Teve um ou outro *post* no blog da empresa sobre nosso site, mas parece eu não teve continuidade (https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/20/estado-da-pilha-internacional-novembro-2016/).

Comment: @bigown, parece que criei a discussão tarde demais, rsrs. O último podcast gravado é recente mas não havia visto a notícia sobre o término do blog. Muito obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Os podcasts na verdade dizem respeito à rede toda, incluindo a parte de Jobs. Não são apenas relativos ao SOen.

Comment: Vocês querem um podcast? O SOes tem um webcast bi-semanal, por exemplo. Ideias? Voluntariamentos?