# Que tal um chat aberto com os assuntos mais "badalados"?

Tags: debate, chat

Acho que seria interessante se tivesse um chat aberto, com os assuntos mais  comentados do momentos e os mais acessados como se fosse um evento sabe, tipo um aulão que poderíamos dar sugestão, comentar e aprender sobre o assunto.

Aí iria aparecer uma notificação no seu perfil que tal horas haverá um evento sobre HTML, CSS, javascript etc...

Comment: Já existe um [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=pt.stackoverflow.com) no SOpt, já tirei várias dúvidas por lá, o pessoal é bem receptivo e informal. Seria isso?

Comment: Nós já tivemos [uma proposta similar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4032/20615) onde foi criado uma sala [somente para Javascript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25038/javascript). Mas, por falta de participação a mesma encontra-se "congelada" hoje. Não sei se o motivo foi a falta de interesse ou se as pessoas desconheciam a sala, mas existem outras do mesmo tipo que foram fechadas. Com base nesses exemplos, não sei se a sala "se manteria" por muito tempo.

Comment: Achei a ideia de eventos muito interessante, mas acho teria que analisar até que ponto as pessoas se comprometeriam em participar, especialmente se tivesse algum palestrante/mediador.

Comment: e isso ai  
acho que iria dar super certo.
  e com a questão do palestrante que você citou ficou melhor ainda ,poderíamos escolher os melhores da comunidade STACKOOVERFLOW para  palestrar ou melhor ainda uma live no propio site.
e uma  questão a ser estudada e acredito que o índice de aprovação seria grande ,basta  nois nos unir e agir de alguma maneira
- sou novo aki mais tenho boas ideias e tarei aqui para ajudar e ser ajudado

Comment: Posso ser taxado como pessimista, mas acho que isso nem vai vingar. Já fizeram algo parecido com um chat chamado debate de pilha e o chat morreu no esquecimento. Pessoal não quer muita complexidade aqui, até porque maioria responde mas também está trabalhando, ai não da pra dedicar a essas coisas.

Comment: STACKOOVERFLOW :P - na verdade é Stack Overflow, separado e só com um "O"

Comment: @Danilorodrigues , sua edição desfigurou a pergunta original. Isso é considerado vandalismo, não faça edições que vandalizam. Você parecia colocar uma coisa totalmente divergente do que tem agora na pergunta, mas não ficou claro qual foi a intenção de edição nem tampouco o texto após a edição ficou legível

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Uma sugestão minha :D

Poderíamos fazer um podcast com os membros da comunidade, a frequência dos podcasts podem ser semanal ou mensal, posteriormente seria decidido a melhor forma. E os assuntos seriam a respeito das tecnologias que já são abordadas pela comunidade (claro que podemos discutir um escopo melhor, e a forma de fazer isto).

Não sei se tem algo a respeito de podcasts aqui no meta, mais fica minha sugestão.

Comment: O que eu sei que tinha [era isso daqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5858/quando-vamos-ter-um-podcast-no-sopt#comment22355_5858). Mas acho que como ninguém se manifestou, o assunto meio que "morreu".

Comment: gostei da ideia tbm 
teremos que fazer um chat so para a galera que ta interessada em melhorar a comunidade

Comment: @Randrade parece que esta pergunta nem recebeu muita atenção e passou despercebida hehe

Comment: Então sua solução seria resolver fora da plataforma? Ok, válido. Sobre salas de chat aqui do SOpt,  chats podem ser abertos de maneira efêmera a vontade

Comment: Eu havia dado essa ideia. Infelizmente ninguém se manifestou. Gosto de ouvir bastante podcasts, mas fazer um é meio difícil pra mim.

Comment: como  eu coloco noticias relacionada no meu site ? alguem pode me ajudar por favor

Comment: Isto é mesmo uma ótima ideia. Gostaria de saber mais sobre como isso pode ser feito!

Comment: @JuanM poderia fazer semanalmente ou mensalmente sem compromisso algum. Podemos discutir a respeito [no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) e ver quem toparia participar de um podcast.

Comment: @cat O que veio desta sugestão?

Answer (score 7):

Eu acho a ideia boa, precisaria planejar, tem ferramenta no site para fazer isso. Só acho que não apareceria muito mais que as pessoas que já participam do [Estouro de Pilha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Se concluírem que deve fazer e como organizar, os moderadores podem fazer algo.

Precisa definir periodicidade, pauta, regras, etc.

Mas não sei se faria sucesso e se seria necessário. Vamos ver as ideias concretas do pessoal pra ver o que pode ser feito.

Comment: esse chat estouro de pilhas e um chat aberto e a pessoas falam sobre muitos assuntos diferente ,e acaba ate fikando meio chato vc qer aprender javascript e as pessoas falando de jogo 
acho que deveria ser exclusivamente sobre o assunto relacionado 
acredito que daria muito certo

Comment: Concordo com você, o chat é usado predominantemente para coisa que nada tem a ver com o site e não deveria.

Comment: e isso ai  <br/>
acho que iria dar super certo.<br/>
  e com a questão do palestrante que o amigo citou ficou melhor ainda ,poderíamos escolher os melhores da comunidade STACKOOVERFLOW para  palestrar ou melhor ainda uma live no propio site.
e uma  questão a ser estudada e acredito que o índice de aprovação seria grande ,basta  nois nos unir e agir de alguma maneira
- sou novo aki mais tenho boas ideias e tarei aqui para ajudar

Comment: como  eu coloco noticias relacionada no meu site ? alguem pode me ajudar por favor

Answer (score 7):

Os sites Stack Overflow (`pt.stackoverflow.com`, `stackoverflow.com`, `jp.stackoverflow.com`, `es.stackoverflow.com` e `ru.stackoverflow.com`) pertencem a empresa Stack Overflow, o foco deles é ser uma Q&A, ou seja um site de **perguntas e respostas** (apesar deles parecerem querer misturar wiki com suporte e etc, que tá meio confuso, mas isto é outra história).

Não tem professores aqui contratados pela empresa, quem responde não tem vinculo com a empresa e pode ser profissional ou um entusiasta, não tem como alguém fazer uma palestra ou dar aulas, nem é este o foco, pode ser até que exista alguma palestras, mas provavelmente será sobre os caminhos dos sites que a empresa pertencem estão tomando, ou seja nada relacionado a tecnologias e ajudar os usuários a aprenderem.

Você pode até tentar fazer algo por si só, mas então sobre notificações e etc, que você comentou:

> Aí iria aparecer uma notificação no seu perfil que tal horas haverá um evento

Eles (a empresa) provavelmente não ajudarão em nada, pois apesar de ser uma comunidade aberta, ainda sim eles são uma empresa e provavelmente financeiramente eles não vão ganhar nada com isto, pelo contrário seria apenas gastos, tanto com a equipe de desenvolvimento deles tanto com tempo, o que no final é gasto financeiro, para algo que não voltaria para eles e sim para nós.

E mesmo que o índice de aprovação "nossa" seja alto não teria muito como eles tornarem isto rentável, pelo menos não em um curto prazo. Não vou entrar em detalhes, pois eu não represento a empresa e não tenho nenhuma ligação com ela, só respondo para tentar esclarecer como funciona e as probabilidades.

### Resumindo

Você pode fazer isso por si só, você mesmo chamar ou convidar as pessoas, mas vai depender se elas vão ter tempo, disposição e realmente vão querer gastar o que tem para dar um *aulão*, tem muito entusiastas bem fraquinhos no site, se você chamar as pessoas erradas com certeza você vai conseguir gente pra ensinar errado, e chamar as pessoas mais preparadas e que realmente entendem do assunto para por o seu tempo e conhecimento dedicando uma hora do seu dia sem nenhum tipo de ganho será algo bem difícil de conseguir.

Comment: como  eu coloco noticias relacionada no meu site ? alguem pode me ajudar por favor

Comment: Que noticias @Danilorodrigues ? Fala de informativos ou feeds relacionados ao StackOverflow ou é outra coisa?

Comment: tipo eu tenho uma sessão no meu site chamada "noticias da politica".
e a pessoa ao clikar na noticia aparecer outras noticias sobre politica abaixo?
tipo veja mais e aparece  mais noticias relacionadas ?

Comment: @Danilorodrigues não vejo como isso se encaixa no **pt.meta.stackoverflow.com**, aqui debatemos sobre o site **pt.stackoverflow.com**, se tem um problema em um site pessoal e afins vá no site principal e crie uma pergunta.

Comment: to meio perdido porque sou novo  nesse site ^^
mais memsmo assim  voce poderia min  dar uma opinião por favor ?kira

Comment: @Danilorodrigues se formular uma pergunta com detalhes talvez dê para entender a sua necessidade, no site principal.

Comment: eu não to podendo fazer perguntas por enquanto não .tenho que esperar  alguns dias para poder fazer outras perguntas 
por isso  que fiz pelo meta ,

Comment: você entendeu a minha pergunta ?deu pra entender mais ou menos 
 a minha pergunta ?

Comment: Entendi, mas como eu já disse, o meta é um local **exclusivo** para falar sobre o pt.stackoverflow.com, como comportamentos, bugs e uso do site, não sobre perguntas de programação, deu para entender agora? Então você não esta podendo perguntar no site principal provavelmente devido a ter deletado perguntas ou respostas, leia isto: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6475/3635

Comment: valew pela atençao